# Simplify PHP files - PHP compression

Tags: php, compression

I know **JavaScript** or **CSS** for expample can be "*compressed*", "*simplified*" in order to be loaded faster. After simplifying they are difficult to be read by humans... and this is exactly what I need.
Is there anyway to make it **automatically**? Rename all variables to short random strings and make it all hypercompressed. I don't think it is a fool thing because I have seen this lot of times in javascript. The idea is to conserve the original source and upload the minified one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compress it, this is basically useless, since you have it on the server and only the output gets transferred to the client.

If you want to make the code more difficult to read for other human beings, you're looking for something which is called an obfuscator.

There are a few php obfuscator engines out there, p.e.

- http://www.codeeclipse.com/
- http://www.truebug.com/
- http://www.raizlabs.com/softwarephpobfuscator/

Comment: Can anyone give me a good example of when/why you would want to obfuscate your code?

Comment: @RobForrest Imagine you want to host it on one elses server (not my case). That was it! Thanks! Great answer.

Comment: @RobForrest Next time my boss or any of my co-workers whine about how hard it is to read my perfectly indented, clean and commented code I'm sending them the obfuscated version. `=]` Very handy to have an obfuscator around.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for doing this. The Server reads the file, and the file never gets transferred to the user.

Therefore, compression is useless because there is no bandwidth saved.

CSS & JavaScript does however get transfered to the user, and therefore they can see it. A user can never see PHP unless you've done something wrong on your server. But then you need to worry about totally different things than compression.

Comment: CSS and JS can bee seen from clients side. PHP can't. At least normaly not.

Comment: @Fluffeh the question was about PHP compression, not CSS & JavaScript. But I clarified it based on Dainis comment

Comment: @DainisAbols Yes, I know... but. What if others have access to my php files? What could be a good way to make it unintelligible for them?

Comment: How would others have access to your PHP files?

Comment: @Kenedy to have access to your PHP files, someone'd have to hack into (or have access to) your ftp server. Read Bjoern's answer if you're looking for an obfuscator.

Comment: @Kenedy There is no solution for that, many think compiliing an app stops this sort of thing hence why some see this as a flaw in PHP but there are so many decompilers now-a-days that compiling no longer does jack to help. You are looking for a security fix which simply is not done on the application end but rather a server and network end.

Comment: @Sammaye The idea is to obfuscate the algorithm, so no one who gets access to the original PHP file will understand how the application works. Do you think it is an impossible task?

Comment: @Kenedy Yes, you can undo this in a matter of seconds with a simple script. All the tool does is move your code around a little to make it human infriendly and in a way more machine friendly.

Comment: @Sammaye Ok... and if I want do do it the most difficult as possible (by hand) how would I do it? Hand done things are IMPOSSIBLE to be undone with a script.

Comment: @Sammaye Before machines there were humans, and life was not impossible. Now, there are more machines than humans... and life is almost impossible. When there are JUST machines, life will have dead. Instead of laughing, why don't you purpose me a human idea? you are human, isn't it?

Comment: @Kenedy Wait you were being serious? The only way would be security through obscurity, but that never works despite a cult following. As you said before computer were humans and humans made the machine and the scripts that run on it as such humans will always understand its flaws

Comment: @Kenedy One last thing, if you were to code obscurely then base64 Obfuscation you could make a persons life hell without a considerable amount of time, I guess thats the key really; make it so time consuming to read your script that they just cant be bothered and give up